# Chose a Photo From Gallery Sample crashed on iOS 10 #26

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have tried follow the tutorial from Xamarin.ios on how to choose a photo from gallary in IOS. Link : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/choose_a_photo_from_the_gallery/

However, there were **no error** when i implemented the codes but it crashes on my simulator when i tried to click on "picker" button. Similar issue to this post : https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/issues/26

Can anyone help me please??? 
Below is my code, which is from Xamarin.

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using AssetsLibrary;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class ImageViewController : UIViewController
    {

    UIImagePickerController imagePicker;
    UIButton choosePhotoButton;
    UIImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewController(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public ImageViewController()
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Title = "Wähle Bild aus:";
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(10, 150, 300, 300));
        Add(imageView);

        choosePhotoButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        choosePhotoButton.Frame = new CGRect(10, 80, 100, 40);
        choosePhotoButton.SetTitle("Picker", UIControlState.Normal);
        choosePhotoButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>
        {
            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();

            imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary);

            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += Handle_Canceled;

            //NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);
            PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);

        };

        View.Add(choosePhotoButton);

    }


    private void Handle_Canceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    }

    protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isImage = false;
        switch (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString())
        {
            case "public.image":
                Console.WriteLine("Image selected");
                isImage = true;
                break;
            case "public.video":
                Console.WriteLine("Video selected");
                break;
        }

        // get common info (shared between images and video)
        NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
        if (referenceURL != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Url:" + referenceURL.ToString());

        // if it was an image, get the other image info
        if (isImage)
        {
            // get the original image
            UIImage originalImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
            if (originalImage != null)
            {
                // do something with the image
                imageView.Image = originalImage; // display
            }

            UIImage editedImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.EditedImage] as UIImage;
            if (editedImage != null)
            {
                // do something with the image
                Console.WriteLine("got the edited image");
                imageView.Image = editedImage;
            }
        }

        // dismiss the picker
        imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does it crash on click of an image in the gallery? Can you do a print line to find out which line is erroring?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Remove the duplicate call to `base.ViewDidLoad();`

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // base.ViewDidLoad();
```

**2)** Replace the `PresentModalViewController` as it was deprecated in iOS 6:

```
    //PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);
    PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);
```

**3)** Since you are accessing the user's photo library, in **iOS10** you have to ask for permission otherwise your app will crash with a:

```
__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__
```

Add an string entry in your app's `info.plist`:

- Property : `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`
- Value : `This app needs to access your photo library`

[image]

This will cause the user to be prompted to accept or deny your app's access

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to make this string in localization? @SushiHangover

Comment: @AlancLiu Info.plist localization: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Comment: I have known about that how to make it work with storyboard in XCode, but I mean how to do that using Xamarin Studio? Is somewhere a button likes it in XCode to localize the plist.info?

Comment: @AlancLiu You create `InfoPlist.strings` files in `Contents/Resources/<language>.lproj directories, these are included in your App bundle. You might want to create an Xcode project, run though Apple's example to understand how to apply this same technique within Xamarin Studio